# which script is freezing apache server

Tags: linux, apache

Sorry for my English. I recently purchased a VPS (Virtual Private Server).  I have no experience with Linux, I forgive you help me to understand.
I'll understood with loading site to the server. Now, the problem is that the site is very slow, and the server is quite good. 
I want to know on what to look for when you use VPS.
Thanks in advance.